# Posting lots of code in a question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, code

I have .aspx and aspx.cs files. And something seems to be not functioning with those files. They are large files and it would be just clumsy to copy and paste those files here. Is there a way to attach files in this site, or any other suitable mechanism??

If there is no alternative I can copy and paste those files here.

Comment: Read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Try to pointpoint *what* is not working, include exception details, and the code that throws the exception. Remove any code that does not seem to be *immediately* related to the problem. Explain where fields and variables come from, and what values they have. That should give you a good start.

Comment: You can't attach files here, but you can find some free host and post link. For example http://jsfiddle.net/ can host JS scripts and even execute them, so I'm sure there are similar services for `.NET` as well.

Comment: The first result in Google gave http://www.mediafire.com/ - while personally I'm not familiar with it, it might fit your needs. By the way, change your display name here so that we can use `@` to send you notifications when you comment on answers, currently I'm not sure you'll see it in your inbox..

Comment: @Shadow you just gave a knife to a toddler.  If someone gets cut, I'm holding you responsible.

Comment: @Will can't see what harm can be done.. hosting the files and posting link asking "please take a look on the file" can't cut anyone. One can refuse to do so (and downvote the question) but one can also take a look and maybe spot something obvious. This is not very different from people posting in jsFiddle tons of HTML/CSS/JS and asking us to have a look and solve something. I won't go and ask every newbie to host his whole files and let us see - this is only in extreme cases like this.

Comment: @Shadow "read my code" is not a real question.  The harm that is done is in the site being brought down with yet another type of low quality question, this one being an insidious version of "debug for me".

Comment: @Will in most cases I agree with you and personally ignore such questions.... but this aside, *sometimes* one quick look can solve in minutes something that the poor person need days to find. If someone says "I've tried everything and hit solid wall" I tend to believe him. Being free community though, other members who think differently can easily close such questions. Hope you see my point?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes; the toddler just shivved me with it.  Agree to disagree, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be spectacularly useless to post tons and tons of code in a question.  Why, on earth, should I take the time to read through fiddy hundred lines of code to find a misplaced semicolon?

Debug, walk through the code, find the relevant lines, post those.  Dumping every line of code in your product is almost as useless as not posting any.  Moreso.  It drives away potential answers.  At least if you post nothing you get some specific requests for more information.

Comment: While I agree in general, there are special cases e.g. when something simply doesn't work and you're totally clueless why. Asking someone to take a peek on the file might be valid request in such extreme case..

Comment: @shadow Thats exactly the case with me. And I don't know where exactly is the error.

Comment: @user158743: So have you tried removing everything you can (e.g. mocking out database calls etc) until you've narrowed it down somewhat? This isn't just part of asking a good question - it's part of troubleshooting in general.

Comment: @Shadow that is an indication that you have not done enough work to even consider asking a question.  @user this is not a time to dump your entire project on StackOverflow, this is time to branch your code (or, more likely in your case, copypaste the code somewhere else) and start (as Jon said) tearing the code out until you DO find where the error is.  *How do you think everybody else who was once in your situation figured it out???*

Answer (score 1):

> And something seems to be not functioning with those files.

Questions like this in combination with much code are not good questions. I tend to downvote and/or vote to close such questions, because they have pretty much no value except the solution `You've missed a semicolon on line x`.

You might want to rethink your strategy. If your question is about a certain error, please share this error and *only directly related* code with us. If there's something wrong with the logic in the code, please only post related code and a short outline of the logic.

Comment: Indeed, if the answer is "You've missed a semicolon on line x" then, in retrospect, the question was not suitable for a Q&A site to start with.

Comment: @Arjan: The question is not suitable for SO if he asks how to attach *multiple big files* to the question. ;)