# Long code snippets that are relevant to the question

Tags: discussion, questions, code, code-block

[Sometimes there's need for including large chunks of data/code in a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582670/query-vs-query-why-is-this-one-quicker-than-the-other). *(See comments to the question: the OP tried to include a couple of long XML files, but that wasn't possible.)*

**What's the recommended approach to including code/data, when there's just too much of it to embed in the question?**

I could think of a few approaches myself:

- Paste the data to a pastebin and link *(and wait for the links to die)*
- Encode the (compressed) data in an image and include that *(kludgy!)*
- Implement an attachment feature in Stack Overflow *(which will probably be abused)*

Comment: This question has been addressed before: [Posting lots of code in a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83104/posting-lots-of-code-in-a-question), [Asking a question with lots of source code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73918/asking-a-question-with-lots-of-source-code).

Comment: But there's no such thing as "too much code to embed in the question". I've never had the system reject a question or answer for being too long, and if it does, then you seriously have too much code. It's unreasonable to suppose that a snippet *that* long can't be trimmed down any further.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I do agree that mostly posting a lot of code equals a bad question, but is there no case at all where it's necessary? Sorry for the duplicateish question, I couldn't find a similar question with the search function.

Comment: Fair enough, the search function has been roundly criticized before. Don't take it personally when people point out duplicates. I suppose that a known-trustworthy site like pastebin is the best option if something like this is *truly* necessary. But I've never seen it. Personally, there's a -20% chance that I'd ever read that much code. There'd better be a heck of a bounty attached.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nobody needs to throw ten tons of code into a question.

## Nobody.

Plus, tl;dr syndrome guarantees that the more crap you throw in a question the more likely it is you won't get an answer.

Hell, I think the max question length should be dropped by 3/4.  I've heard that skill in asking a question is more important than length.  Or was it column width?  Anyhow, a massive code dump smells like what it sounds like.  Stop it.  Don't.

Comment: +1. “If I had more time, I would have written a shorter letter.”
 -Marcus Tullius Cicero, philosopher and statesman.

Comment: Absolutely "tl;dr syndrom guarantees that the more crap you throw in a question the more likely it is you won't get an answer" - when I see walls of code, I generally just post a comment asking them to pare it down or I just move on, I don't even bother trying to dissect the whole thing.