# Why can't code snippet fields be re-sized to avoid scrolling?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, code-formatting

I'm not sure if this is a dumb question, but why can't the < code > class and its wrapper be vertically re-sized, to allow viewers to view more code without having to scroll (or, at the very least, seeing more lines of code and scrolling less)?  It would be minimally intrusive but would allow users with more screen real estate to take advantage of screen size, IMHO.

A super-basic example, to clarify what I mean: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_resize.

Comment: ["Nobody needs to throw ten tons of code into a question."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87525/165773)

Comment: You are totally right. Sure, people should be specific and give _good_ questions, but it happens all the time, right? Scrolling is more a hindrance to the person trying to help, not really as much a limitation on the OP it seems...

Comment: I'm trying to see the difference between scrolling the code snippet and scrolling the web page and am failing at it.  Having a choice which one you want to scroll sounds like a feature, not a problem.

Comment: @UphillLuge, did you check out the example I linked above? If you have a code snippet of fixed height that scrolls, you can't see as many lines simultaneously; if you scroll the web page the entire code div moves. Please view it if you are confused as to what I mean

Comment: @UphillLuge not to mention that to scroll the code you have to put your mouse in it: the more convenient page down won't work. Seeing less lines is even more critical for ASCII art: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23877420/895245

Comment: possible cross-site duplicate of: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254534/why-isnt-the-code-area-of-a-question-resizable